# manage many database

Tags: java, spring, dao, spring-jdbc

I search a way in a spring 3.x application to manage many database.
Now we support mysql, but we need to support firebird and postgress sql.

we don't use orm.

what is the best way to support many database with spring?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have multiple data sources - one for each JDBC driver you need.  You'll have to find a way to select which one you want for a give case.

Comment: there are not any standart way to do it with spring?

Comment: That is the standard way.  One driver per data source, right?  Multiple drivers means multiple data sources.

Answer (score 0):

Once you define a data source per database, as duffymo said, define a transaction-manager for each, and you can use @Transactional("managerXname") for declarative transaction demarcation.

Comment: i don't search to use database at the same time